# SEDE using graph with number, string, number [, number ...]

Tags: support, data-explorer, graphs

The query [use of certain given tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/460510) in the last quarters returns a format that according my understanding of the [graphing help](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#graphing) should be suitable to be rendered as a graph: `number, string, number [, number, number]` and `... additional number columns`

But this is not the case.
What am I misunderstading, and how can I change the query to render a graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The help topic is a bit misleading, additional number columns can actually only be added to the first two combinations (`number, number` and `date, number`). I'll make a note to update this.

The last two combinations (`number, string, number` and `date, string, number`) produce multiple series by aggregating results based on the string column and then displaying those on the graph (as a sort of unpivot), which is why this doesn't work in those cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the clarification. I guess i partly got it. I created a [test query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/460886/) for the combination `number, string, number` . I assume if i would change my query linked above to not use pivot and create records matching the combination from the test case i should be able to create an output that is a fit.

Comment: I modified my query for certain [javascirpt frameworks](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/461038#graph) and now a graph is rendered. Thanks again.